# Oracle: Compare two versions of a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

If one user changes the source code of a procedure, I want to find the differences between the new version and the old version of the procedure and save them into a table.
In other words i want to find the added, modified or deleted lines. 

I tried to use a trigger with "before ddl on schema" and then comparing the source code from the all_source view and the source code given by the function ORA_SQL_TXT(sql_text), but this doesn't work because the source code given by the function ORA_SQL_TXT(sql_text) is not ordered by the line number.

Comment: Why not use a DIFF tool (WinDIFF, KDIFF, etc), copy & paste what you want?

Comment: No I need a solution without an external tool

Comment: How about using a before DDL on schema trigger to read/write the old version from all_source, and an after ddl on schema trigger to read/write the new version from all_source?

Comment: This sounds good. But then i have to save the old version into a new table temporarily, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @user1720132 or an array (create a package spec to hold a before array + after array then you can compare them post DDL).

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT .. FROM USER_SOURCES AS OF TIMESTAMP(time you want) WHERE ... ORDER BY LINE;`. This will give the table as it was prior in time, from this you can use `MINUS` or put that into another table and do whatever you want.

It saves only recent changes (depending on some settings), but is an absolutely wonderful feature whan doing a small mistake.